# Archive xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

My application uses an additional project I have inserted, and I link it and then import it with this code:

```
#import <SBJson/SBJson.h>
```

If I run the application normally, the app works fine, but if I press the archive button, there is an error in the line of code reported above. It says: SBJson/SBJson.h file not found. Why is this?? IS it because the JSON is a project I added to my project? Why does it work with the Run and not with the Archive?

Comment: Have you tried a make clean and Run again? Sounds a lot as if the problem is not related to Archive. Also, SBJson is not a system provided component and hence should be imported using quotes ("") instead of <>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have linked the **SBJSON** files, when you probably should actually have **copied** them into your project.

To fix this, select all of the SBJSON files, right-click and then select "delete". When prompted, select "remove references".

Then, add these files back into your project via File -> Add files to menu and make sure that "copy files" checkbox is selected.

Comment: Try deleting the SBJSON files from the project and copying them into it again as explained above. Let me know if this doesn't work, and I'll try to help further. Good luck.

Comment: Didn't work. I first deleted the project and re added it, no way, then just the files, and it said both times that it couldnt find the location (I think, something like user/....), there were no code problems though